# Array to CSV add separator between every character

Tags: javascript, csv, alasql

I'm using alasql to convert into CSV:

```
data = ["402 Fourth Avenue", "11 Russell Avenue", "East Diamond Avenue"];

function exportData(list) {
    alasql.promise('SELECT * INTO CSV("test.csv", {separator:" "} ) FROM ?',list)
     .then(function(data){
         console.log('Data saved');
    }).catch(function(err){
         console.log('Error:', err);
    });
}
```

When I pass it through the function my result ends up like this:

```
4 0 2   "F" "o" "u" "r" "t" "h"   "A" "v" "e" "n" "u" "e"
```

I cannot figure out why! Thank you in advance you will make my day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this example](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/How%20to%20export%20JavaScript%20array%20info%20to%20csv%20on%20client%20side) in the documentation, the argument should be a 3-dimensional array.

- The first dimension corresponds to the placeholders (`?`) in the query.
- The second dimension is the rows of the CSV.
- The third dimension is the columns in the CSV.

So `data` should be a 2-dimensional array, and then you should wrap it in another array when calling `alasql`.

```
data = [["402 Fourth Avenue"], ["11 Russell Avenue"], ["East Diamond Avenue"]];

function exportData(list) {
    alasql.promise('SELECT * INTO CSV("test.csv", {separator:" "} ) FROM ?',[list])
     .then(function(data){
         console.log('Data saved');
    }).catch(function(err){
         console.log('Error:', err);
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you!! My array wasn't up to snuff. Much appreciated!